# Unable to generate PDF/A with `marvosym` package

Tags: fonts, pdftex, symbols, pdf-a

I am unable to generate a PDF file that is compliant to PDF/A (version 1b) when using fonts of the `marvosym` package.

A minimal working example is the following:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\begin{document}
\Libra
\end{document}
```

I compile with `pdflatex` of the MiKTeX package. When checking the resulting PDF for PDF/A compliance, there are error messages that glyphs are missing in the embedded font and that width information is inconsistent for printed glyphs.

Is there a way to use the above Libra symbol and generate a PDF/A compliant output?

Comment: How do you check for PDF/A? Can you add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and check?

Comment: I added the `fontenc` package, but it didn't help. I check PDF/A compliance with either Adobe Acrobat Pro or the upload tool of our University's library.